# Computed coordinates are all the same?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

It's embarrassing question time. Why are my computed coordinates **all** showing up at the same location?  The larger filled quarter circles are drawn with:

```
current page.\x
```

where `\x` is `south west`, `north west`, `north east`, `south east`, and these work just fine.  But when I compute my own locations as:

```
\coordinate (South West) ($(current page.south west) + ( \XMargin, \XMargin)$) ;
\coordinate (North West) ($(current page.north west) + ( \XMargin,-\XMargin)$) ;
\coordinate (North East) ($(current page.north east) + (-\XMargin,-\XMargin)$) ;
\coordinate (South East) ($(current page.south east) + (-\XMargin, \XMargin)$) ;
```

they all show at the same location, as shown by the concentric circles:

[image]

The correct output should have those concentric circles distributed around the page.

### References:

- [Is there a \show for lengths?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558/is-there-a-show-for-lengths)

### Code:

```
\def\PaperWidth{3.0 in}
\def\PaperHeight{2.0 in}
\def\Bleed{0.15 in}
\def\SafetyMargin{0.35 in}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    paperwidth=\PaperWidth,
    paperheight=\PaperHeight,
    margin=\dimexpr\Bleed+\SafetyMargin\relax,
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{printlen}\uselengthunit{in}
\newlength{\XMargin}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathsetlength{\XMargin}{\Bleed + \SafetyMargin}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
    
    \coordinate (South West) ($(current page.south west) + ( \XMargin, \XMargin)$) ;
    \coordinate (North West) ($(current page.north west) + ( \XMargin,-\XMargin)$) ;
    \coordinate (North East) ($(current page.north east) + (-\XMargin,-\XMargin)$) ;
    \coordinate (South East) ($(current page.south east) + (-\XMargin, \XMargin)$) ;

    % Why are these all showing up at the same point???
    \foreach [count=\xi] \x/\Color/\InnerSep  in {South West/orange/4, North West/brown/5, North East/red/6, South East/blue/7} {
        \node [circle, draw=\Color, inner sep=\InnerSep pt] at (\x) {\xi};
    }
    
    % This works just fine
    \foreach \x/\Color in {south west/orange, north west/brown, north east/red, south east/blue} {
        \node [circle, fill=\Color, inner sep=0.25in] at (current page.\x) {};
    }

    \node at (current page.center) {xmargin is \printlength{\XMargin}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OMG, just figured it out!!! Can't believe that that took me soooo long. I'll wait some time before posting an, in case others like a challenge... :-)

Comment: `at` (Damn character minimum.)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Damm you are quick. Yep that is where it is `at`. You should post an answer. Don't know why that did not trigger a syntax error though.

Comment: Also `\coordinate (SW) at ([shift={( \XMargin, \XMargin)}]current page.south west) ;` to skip the `calc` lib. You are being punished for using inches :P

Comment: @percusse: Well unfortunately I am in the US and they use the British System. Even the British don't use the British System!!!

Comment: I also wonder why the missing `at` with a coordinate involved  doesn't trigger a message error.

Comment: @PeterGrill Isn't it correctly known as the Imperial System?

Comment: @Canageek: Perhaps, but the point I was trying to make is better when you refer to it as the "British System". The US is so ass backwards sometimes, especially on things that should be intuitively obvious.

Comment: @PeterGrill I don't think they are synonyms though; As I recall some of the measurements are different between the British and Imperial systems, though I could be getting the names mixed up.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, as you already figured out, you missed an `at` in your coordinate specification:

```
\coordinate (South West) at ($(current page.south east) + (-\XMargin, \XMargin)$);
\coordinate (North West) at ($(current page.south west) + ( \XMargin, \XMargin)$);
\coordinate (North East) at ($(current page.north west) + ( \XMargin,-\XMargin)$);
\coordinate (South East) at ($(current page.north east) + (-\XMargin,-\XMargin)$);
```

---

[image: Oh, so bubbly!]

Answer (score 8):

Just to answer the query in the comments:

> I also wonder why the missing `at` with a coordinate involved doesn't trigger a message error.

The reason is that `\coordinate (South West) ($(current page.south west) + ( \XMargin, \XMargin)$) ;` is a completely valid TikZ command.  It says "Mark `(0,0)` as a coordinate with label `South West` and then move to `(complicated point)`.".  The `(0,0)` is because there isn't an explicit coordinate specification and the coordinate dimensions are all set to `0` at the start of a path.  The interpretation is because (in the absence of `beamer`), `\coordinate` expands to `\path coordinate` and so the command is:

```
\path coordinate (South West) ($(current page.south west) + ( \XMargin, \XMargin)$) ;
```

which is completely valid.  Of course, it doesn't do anything (apart from mess with the bounding box) but it does mean that you could do:

```
\coordinate (a) (0,1) [draw] -- (2,0) coordinate (b);
```

and it would draw a line from `(0,1)` to `(2,0)` and stick another coordinate there.  What you *can't* do is:

```
\coordinate[draw] (a) -- (2,0);
```

for two reasons: the path doesn't get it's official initial move (the coordinate is at `(0,0)` but the path hasn't actually *moved* there), and the `draw` command is given to the `coordinate` node where it does nothing (since `coordinate` nodes have no shape).

Now, of course, if you were planning on anything more complicated than `\coordinate (a) at (38,42);` then you'd probably use a `\path` (or `\draw` or `\fill`) to begin with.  So this is probably unnecessary if it were there to make `\coordinate` more flexible.  But it isn't, it's there to ensure that `\coordinate` behaves *exactly* like `\path coordinate` so that you have peace of mind in knowing that however you specify coordinates, they all turn out just the same.

Some code to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/79358/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) (0,1) [draw] -- (2,0) coordinate (b);
\draw (a) to[bend left] (2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: complicated coordinate specifications]