# How many pixels, inches or centi meters is a linewidth in a two columned article?

Tags: two-column, width

I'm writing an article. The article consists of two columns and is created using:

```
\documentclass[10pt, aps, prb, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
```

How long is a `1.\linewidth` in pixels, inches or centi meters?

Comment: `\linewidth` doesn't have a fixed value (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16942/difference-between-textwidth-linewidth-and-hsize). You probably want to know the value of `\columnwidth`: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558/is-there-a-show-for-lengths

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out by asking LaTeX itself.

Open a console/terminal window, and type `latex`.

LaTeX will respond with some version information text and then a prompt `**`. You can then issue commands, as

```
**\documentclass[10pt, aps, prb, twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
*\begin{document}
*\showthe\linewidth
```

LaTeX will then return the value of `\linewidth`, which on my system is 246.0 pt.