# Displaying rubber lengths in arbitrary units

Tags: lengths

[Based on this question,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/558/is-there-a-show-for-lengths) I know how to show regular lengths expressed in arbitrary units.  However, I need to do the same for rubber lengths (showing the plus and minus) and the `printlen` package doesn't support that except for pt.  Is there an equivalent that will work for rubber lengths?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

etex has additional primitives for extracting the components so that you can print them separately:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{printlen}


\begin{document}

\the\parskip


The \verb|\parskip| is \printlength{\dimexpr\parskip\relax} which is also
\uselengthunit{in}\printlength{\dimexpr\parskip\relax} and
\uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\dimexpr\parskip\relax}.


The \verb|\gluestretch\parskip| is \printlength{\gluestretch\parskip} which is also
\uselengthunit{in}\printlength{\gluestretch\parskip} and
\uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\gluestretch\parskip}.


The \verb|\glueshrink\parskip| is \printlength{\glueshrink\parskip} which is also
\uselengthunit{in}\printlength{\glueshrink\parskip} and
\uselengthunit{mm}\printlength{\glueshrink\parskip}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this a good command: `\newcommand{\myprtlen}[2]{\uselengthunit{#1}\printlength{\dimexpr#2\relax}~plus~\printlength{\gluestretch#2}~minus~\printlength{\glueshrink#2}}`

Comment: @Sigur you might want to also test `\gluestretchorder` and `\glueshrinkorder` in case the plus or minus component is fill glue like `\hfill`

Comment: Using @DavidCarlisle's answer I created the following function: `\newcommand{\printrubberlength}[1]{\printlength{#1}\ifdim\gluestretch#1=0pt\relax\else\ plus \printlength{\gluestretch#1}\fi\ifdim\glueshrink#1=0pt\relax\else\ minus \printlength{\glueshrink#1}\fi}` which nicely fits my bill.  I don't have fills to worry about here.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version using `expl3` that also takes care of infinite components.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\printglue}{O{pt}m}
 { % #1 = unit, #2 = glue
  \rpspringuel_print_glue:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \rpspringuel_print_glue:nn #1 #2
 {
  \skip_set:Nn \l_rpspringuel_input_skip { #2 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_rpspringuel_natural_dim { \l_rpspringuel_input_skip }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_rpspringuel_stretch_dim
   { \rpspringuel_gluestretch:n { \l_rpspringuel_input_skip } }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_rpspringuel_shrink_dim
   { \rpspringuel_glueshrink:n { \l_rpspringuel_input_skip } }
  \int_set:Nn \l_rpspringuel_stretch_order_int
   { \rpspringuel_gluestretchorder:n { \l_rpspringuel_input_skip } }
  \int_set:Nn \l_rpspringuel_shrink_order_int
   { \rpspringuel_glueshrinkorder:n { \l_rpspringuel_input_skip } }
  % print the components
  \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_natural_dim } { 1#1 }
  \,#1
  \c_space_tl
  plus
  \c_space_tl
  \int_case:nn { \l_rpspringuel_stretch_order_int }
   {
    { 0 } { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_stretch_dim } { 1#1 }\,#1 }
    { 1 } { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_stretch_dim } { 1pt }\,fil }
    { 2 } { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_stretch_dim } { 1pt }\,fill }
    { 3 } { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_stretch_dim } { 1pt }\,filll }
   }
  \c_space_tl
  minus
  \c_space_tl
  \int_case:nn { \l_rpspringuel_shrink_order_int }
   {
    { 0 } { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_shrink_dim } { 1#1 }\,#1 }
    { 1 } { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_shrink_dim } { 1pt }\,fil }
    { 2 } { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_shrink_dim } { 1pt }\,fill }
    { 3 } { \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn { \l_rpspringuel_shrink_dim } { 1pt }\,filll }
   }
 }

\skip_new:N \l_rpspringuel_input_skip
\dim_new:N \l_rpspringuel_natural_dim
\dim_new:N \l_rpspringuel_stretch_dim
\dim_new:N \l_rpspringuel_shrink_dim
\int_new:N \l_rpspringuel_stretch_order_int
\int_new:N \l_rpspringuel_shrink_order_int

\cs_new:Npn \rpspringuel_gluestretch:n #1
 {
  \etex_gluestretch:D \etex_glueexpr:D #1\scan_stop:
 }
\cs_new:Npn \rpspringuel_glueshrink:n #1
 {
  \etex_glueshrink:D \etex_glueexpr:D #1\scan_stop:
 }
\cs_new:Npn \rpspringuel_gluestretchorder:n #1
 {
  \etex_gluestretchorder:D \etex_glueexpr:D #1\scan_stop:
 }
\cs_new:Npn \rpspringuel_glueshrinkorder:n #1
 {
  \etex_glueshrinkorder:D \etex_glueexpr:D #1\scan_stop:
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printglue{\parskip}

\printglue{\fill}

\newlength\mylength

\setlength\mylength{10cm plus 1cm minus 1filll}

\printglue[cm]{\mylength}

\printglue[mm]{10cm plus 1cm minus 1filll}

\end{document}
```

Note that there's no public interface for `\gluestretch`, `\gluestretchorder`, `\glueshrink` and `\glueshrinkorder`, so I defined one.

Rounding can give unexpected results; this might be improved using the `fp` module.

[image]

Comment: Off topic: did you type the whole code or do you have auto completion editor?

Comment: @Sigur: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19587864#19587864 :-)

Comment: @Sigur Where's the problem? `;-)` Some judicious “copy, paste and replace” makes repetitive code easy to type.