# How to parsing a length with skip/rubber/glue?

Tags: lengths

Others have asked about [getting length as a number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15001/getting-length-as-number); the solutions there (using `\strip@pt` to remove the units, or using `\number` to convert to an integer number of `sp` units) work fine for a regular length but not for one with skip/glue (as described in [What is glue stretching?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64756/what-is-glue-stretching)).

For example, the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newlength\testlength
\setlength\testlength{10pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
length: \the\testlength\par
\textbackslash strip@pt: \csname strip@pt\endcsname\testlength\par
\textbackslash number: \number\testlength\par
\end{document}
```

prints:

```
length: 10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt
\strip@pt: 10 plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt
\number: 655360
```

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Subsequent searching found clues in an [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/186117/134609) to "[Mathematical description of TeX's infinite numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/186115/mathematical-description-of-texs-infinite-numbers)" and "[Displaying rubber lengths in arbitrary units](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229292/displaying-rubber-lengths-in-arbitrary-units)". The following

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newlength\testlength
\setlength\testlength{10pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
length: \the\testlength\par
\textbackslash dimexpr: \the\dimexpr\testlength\par
\textbackslash gluestretch: \the\gluestretch\testlength\par
\textbackslash gluestretchorder: \the\gluestretchorder\testlength\par
\textbackslash glueshrink: \the\glueshrink\testlength\par
\textbackslash glueshrinkorder: \the\glueshrinkorder\testlength\par
\end{document}
```

prints:

```
length: 10.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 1.0pt
\dimexpr: 10.0pt
\gluestretch: 2.0pt
\gluestretchorder: 0
\glueshrink: 1.0pt
\glueshrinkorder: 0
```