# Page size defined by a41.sty changes when using graphicx

Tags: graphics, pdftex, paper-size

I observed a strange issue if you combine the `graphicx` package and `a41.sty`. The page size changes if I compile the document using `pdflatex`

**Disclaimer**: I know that using `a41.sty` is heavily outdated and deprecated. It's not my choice to use it and I'm afraid its beyond my authority to switch to more modern ways to adjust the paper size to A4. I'd just like to understand the interference of these two packages under the given constraints.

### Expected behaviour

By using `a41.sty` the paper size should be changed to A4 and the margins should be adjusted to be rather small. Including the `graphicx` package should not change anything about the page size.

### Observed behaviour

As long as I only include `a41.sty` the margins look as expected. When I include the `graphicx` package and use `pdflatex` to compile the document, the page size becomes significantly smaller and the page number is placed quite close to the border of the page. Using `latex`, however, both versions (with and without `graphicx`) produce the same output.

[Output with graphicx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcsEg.png)

[Output without graphicx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mg2c.png)

### Question

Can anyone explain what exactly is happening here? Is there a way to avoid this problem (besides switching to `geometry` or `typearea`)?

### Minimal working example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{a41}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}
% insert filler text
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

### a41.sty

Since it's not very widespread here is the contents of a41.sty:

```
% Correction for A4 paper (297x210mm) instead of the american 11x8.5in.         
% To be called, for example, in this way:                                       
%                 \documentstyle[12pt,A4]{article}                              
\addtolength{\textheight}{154.6pt}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{100pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-92pt}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{0.5cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-52pt}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.2cm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-52pt}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.2cm}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`graphics` (and `geometry` and one or two other modern (ie, post pdftex) packages) pass the values of `\paperheight` and `\paperwidth` to the PDF output as `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth` so that a PDF viewer uses the intended page size.

If you use the standard `[a4paper]`option on the documentclass these would be set to A4 but as you have not, the default USLetter size is being used.

The comment in the file betrays its age

```
\documentstyle[12pt,A4]{article}
```

That is latex2.09 usage so pre 1993. there  isn't really any reason to use that now, use the geometry package instead.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation concerning \pdfpageheight. This piece of information actually helped to convince the other people on the project to finally switch to the geometry package. I ended up using `\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=490.0pt,textheight=703.1pt]{geometry}` to keep the exact dimensions of the text area of the a41.sty given above (for compatibility). To find out these values I used `\showthe\textwidth` and `\showthe\textheight` (see [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/558/77149)) in the old document while using a41.sty.