# Tikz package altering footer

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer

I had two almost identical documents that were done using the exam class. The one difference between the documents was the tikz package. The document with the tikz package had the page numbers where I wanted and the document without tikz had the page numbers higher up on the page. I like the place the tikz package put my footer. This leads me to my question, how can I get it to be that same way without having

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

in my preamble?

Relevant Preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\runningheadrule
\firstpageheader{Test}{Answers}{}
\runningheader{Test}{Solutions}{}
\firstpagefooter{}{}{\thepage}
\runningfooter{}{}{\thepage}
```

Comment: I added `\usepackage{lipsum}` and `\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}` to your document and cannot reproduce your issue. Please provide a complete document that shows it.

Comment: @marmot the issue happens when you have tikz active and when you do not have it active. When you have tikz in the preamble the pagenumber goes to the very bottom right. When you do not have tikz the pagenumber is significantly further up

Comment: Well, I tried that and fail to reproduce this on my machine. I use a TeXLive 2019 distribution on a Mac. Please consider completing your document.

Comment: The difference seems to resemble that between `letterpaper` and `a4paper`. Try to add either as optional argument to the documentclass and check if that solves your issue.

Comment: It isn't TikZ directly that does this, but the `graphicx` package which TikZ loads. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/335086, which is the same problem I think.