# a5paper option in documentclass produces strange white space/margins and hyperref fixes it

Tags: paper-size, white-space, documentclass

I observed a very strange behaviour of latex when it comes to the pagesize:

When I create a document in `a5paper` by just using `\documentclass[a5paper]{book}` then the output pdf seems to be in `A4` but the printed area is `A5`, which results in a lot of white space or strange margins if you want so.

The following code produces this strange behaviour

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt,pagesize]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
hallo
\end{document}
```

[image: a5 that doesn't really work]

The same happens for `report` and `article`.
Interestingly, using the `hyperref` package fixes this issue. The following code produces what I would expect in the first place:

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 10pt,pagesize]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepacakge{hyperref}

\begin{document}
hallo
\end{document}
```

I have also read that one can fix this issue by using the `geometry` package and in particular `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` (with the `pass` option) to suppress the layout changes of `geometry`.

I am some how puzzled why the `a5paper` option isn't working on its own the way someone would expect it and how `hyperref` is fixing it. Is this a bug? Should this be reported to the developers? And who are these developers (which team is maintaining the standard classes `book`, `report`, `article`)?

Comment: the (rather old) standard classes don't contain the needed code to set the pdf size. This will perhaps change at some time (the classes are maintained by the LaTeX team). For now you will have to load a package. I suggest the graphicx package or geometry, hyperref adds the needed code currently too, but imho this is a bit awkward and it will be removed from there probably (I already removed it when the new pdfmanagement is used).

Comment: the answer I just linked to is the case with graphicx rather than hyperref but it is the same thing really.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the question is not the same but the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389951/143676 also covers my concerns