# Why merely including the package color changes the page size, and how to determine whether the package color is really used?

Tags: color

Let's consider a system where A4 is the default paper size and the input

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}% take it or leave it
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

With `\usepackage{color}`, running either of `latex`+`dvipdf` (with default options), or `lualatex`, or `pdflatex` yields a letter-size PDF file (as reported by `pdfinfo`), whereas without `\usepackage{color}`, the PDF output stays at A4 (again, as reported by `pdfinfo`).

1. WHY do the page dimensions change?  Intuitively, shouldn't adding color support leave the page size in peace?

For the purpose of determining whether `color` is actually needed in a longer, non-minimal document (say, 15 pages with LLNCS class, which you can no longer understand without investing hours to days), we decide to format the document the way `color` wants it and enforce letter size wherever we can.  For our minimal example, we run `mwe.tex` containing

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{color}% take it or leave it
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

through  `latex main && latex main && dvips -t letter -Ppdf -q -f main.dvi | gs -q -P- -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=main.pdf -sPAPERSIZE=letter -`.  Alas, the comparison of the results is sobering:

[image: output]

`diffpdf` says there's a difference (and, in a larger document, there's a difference *everywhere*), but you don't see any. Perhaps, at low resolutions, the `color`ed version might be a tiny little grayer compared to the non-`color`ed version, but you cannot really tell, and such a tiny difference, should it exist, would not matter to you.

Before you ask: we tried `[a4paper]` (instead of `[letterpaper]`) and `latex main && latex main && dvips -t a4 -Ppdf -q -f main.dvi | gs -q -P- -dSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=main.pdf -sPAPERSIZE=a4 -`. The outcome is the same: `diffpdf` reports the difference, whereas we don't see any difference (or any that would matter).

2. How would you determine whether using the package `color` really incurs any prominently visible difference?

EDIT: Following David's suggestion, we run `latex` on

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nosetpagesize]{color}% take it or leave it
\showoutput
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

and get

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(682.0+0.0)x398.0
.\hbox(0.0+0.0)x0.0
..\special{header=l3backend-dvips.pro}
.\glue 17.0
.\vbox(665.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 53.0
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
....\special{color push  Black}
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0
....\special{color pop}
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(598.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 587.9372fil
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 3.84921
...\hbox(6.15079+0.0)x345.0, glue set 313.83331fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 e
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 s
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 t
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.55556
..\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0
...\special{color push  Black}
...\hbox(6.44444+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 1
....\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\special{color pop}
.\kern 0.0
```

The diff (on the left — with `color`, on the right – without) is this:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty        <
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg)   <
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/dvips.def)   <
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def))   <
....\special{color push  Black}                                    <
....\special{color pop}                                            <
...\special{color push  Black}                                     <
...\special{color pop}                                             <
Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 332 bytes).                    |    Output written on main.dvi (1 page, 248 bytes).
```

Do these `\special` commands affect the text somehow? We don't know Postscript, so we can't tell …

Comment: color and graphics share backend files dvips.def, luatex.def etc, latex can not set the media size until it knows which backend is in use

Comment: essentially a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/389951/1090

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you! I guess, that's your answer to Question 1, and `\usepackage[nosetpagesize]{color}` will effectively not set letter size in advance, right? As for our Question 2, I still don't know what to do.

Comment: as for your last question `\showoutput`  will show all the differences

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Got it, thanks! We see `\special`s, but we can't really tell whether pushing and poping the black color affects anything visibly. In fact, for a large document, the only difference we get due to `\showoutput` are `\special{color push  Black}` and `\special{color pop}`.

Comment: if you use the option [a4paper] you change also the \textheight as that is calculated from \paperheight. It will therefore change not only the paper size but also the textbody and the layout.

Comment: so that is no change in position and just explicity setting Black